# How can I determine which Stack Exchange Community to ask in?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question I want to ask about the date standard ISO 8601. I do not want to post it to the wrong community because (a) it won’t help, and (b) it won’t help anybody else.

I know that there is a long list of possible forums, and I’ve looked through it. I’m pretty sure that it’s not **Buddhism**, **French** or **Photography**, but I can’t find one which addresses ISO standards.

The question is, how can I find an appropriate community to ask that question? Is there some sort of advanced search which allows me to search all communities for similar questions?

My current question is:

> Why is the Monday the first day of the week, rather than Sunday?
>
> Historically, it has generally been Sunday, with Saturday being the Seventh. Both JavaScript and PHP number the days from 0-6, with Sunday being 0. Yet ISO 8601 has determined that Monday is day 1 and Sunday is day 7.

As noted, my particular question regards the ISO standard, but the question itself, I think, is appropriate to any new question.

Comment: How/ where you would be using said standards might be relevant

Comment: There's a number of questions about iso 8601 to be found at [Stack Overflow](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=iso+8601+stack+overflow&*).

Comment: Generally, the place to figure this out is just to ask here on MSE, so you're pretty much there.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: The question is about the standard itself — specifically why certain decisions were made — so it’s more a general question. The trouble with Stack Overflow is that if it’s not a programming question, it tends to get voted down rather than answered.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: See my additional comment above (I can only notify one commenter … ?)

Comment: @NathanTuggy So if I ask the question here, someone will be kind enough to direct me to the right place? Should I edit this question or ask a new one?

Comment: If you want to know why decisions were made about a standard the best place to ask is the discussion list for that standard i.e. not on any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @Manngo Well, you have to formulate your question very carefully, not being to broad or opinion based. You may ask something like: _What is the reasoning for having part X in standard Y?_

Comment: Just edit this a bit, although it really doesn't need much.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I have added the question into this one.

Comment: Yep, Nathan is right. This is the place to ask where to ask, and that [site-recommendation] tag is for this very purpose.

Comment: The general guidelines is 1.Search through [SE](http://stackexchange.com/search) 2.Check /help/on-topic of particular site 3.Search for similar question on specific site 4.Try discussing in chat room of specific site.

Answer (score 2):

In general, ways to find out are:

- First, of course, search for the solution. You may very well find that your question has already been posted on an SE site at some point in the past. 9 times out of 10, your quest ends here.
- If you're pretty sure that it belongs on a certain site, you can check out some of the other questions on the site. Look for ones that are similar to yours, look at the tags, see if they were well received, etc.
- You can also ask on a specific site's meta, or even in a site's chat room.
- If you have no idea where to ask it, you can ask here on MSE (it's what [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) is for, after all), which will have a few possible outcomes:

  - You'll be told exactly where to ask it. Mission accomplished.
  - You'll end up with a short list of possibilities, in which case, as above, look at the questions there, ask on their meta if you're not sure, etc.
  - You'll be told that there are no appropriate sites, in which case, bummer.
- If you're *reasonably sure* a question belongs on a certain site, but not *entirely* clear even after doing a little bit of research, just ask it. Worst case it ends up being poorly received (if this happens too often it's a problem but every once in a while, you know, it happens). It could also be migrated. Or it could become clear in comments that you should have asked it elsewhere. Or it was totally appropriate, well-received, and you get an answer.

A lot of sites have overlap so you might find that your question is appropriate in more than one place, in which case you just have to make a choice.

---

As for your particular question, it's a little tricky because it kind of depends on the context. Are you asking for religious reasons? Programming reasons (if it's causing an issue in some code perhaps you could be more specific about that)? User interface reasons (e.g. the UX site if you're having representation / presentation problems)? Etc.

The other thing that makes it tricky is it's a bit difficult to answer questions like "Why did such-and-such committee make such-and-such choice" in general, and may not be entirely well-received anywhere. In fact, it appears [you've already discovered this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170496/why-did-the-iso-8601-committee-choose-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week) for this particular question.

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170496/why-did-the-iso-8601-committee-choose-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week closed as offtopic! Lol. Wrong forum I guess

Comment: @NoahCristino Lol, yeah, I found that too and linked to it. So did the OP here, looking at the comments there (they did the right thing by searching and finding that). Kinda funny.